# Use Realm DB in flutter app with native swift code

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, realm

I would like to know if it's possible to use Realm DB in an app developed with Flutter by using cocoapods and Swift language.

Even it's not very easy, I have understood that we can use native code in Flutter, so would it be possible to develop an app in Flutter but develop in Swift the database/backend to be able to use Realm DB ?

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: I'm sure you can do it with platform channels.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I'll learn more about platform channels !

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the [Realm Flutter SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/).